# AppEngine PHP storage not working in production

Tags: php, google-app-engine

```
$file = 'gs://myapp.appspot.com/storage.json';

file_put_contents($file, $array);
$response = file_get_contents($file);
```

This works fine when I run appengine locally, but doesn't work in production. Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the bucket name is wrong. Try something like this which looks up the bucket name at runtime.

```
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;

$bucket = CloudStorageTools::getDefaultGoogleStorageBucketName();
$file = "gs://$bucket/storage.json";
file_put_contents($file, $array);
$response = file_get_contents($file);
```